# Integrating Azure AD into a Java web application. How to break Azure AD

Tags: java, azure, azure-active-directory

We integrated our Java app with Azure Active Directory. So the issue that we’re having at the moment is that Azure Active Directory Session is not destroyed when the Spring Security session is destroyed
(for example if Tomcat is restarted on the WEB server)

Is there way to tell which parameter identifies Azure Active Directory session? Or in general would you have any suggestions on how to handle this in the best way?

We used this example to integrate our Java app with Active Directory.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/resources/samples/active-directory-java-webapp-openidconnect/

Thanks,

Andy G.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is the section [`Send a sign-out request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-protocols-openid-connect-code#send-a-sign-out-request) of the offical document `Authorize access to web applications using OpenID Connect and Azure Active Directory` introduces how to sign the user out of your app, as below.

> **Send a sign-out request**
>
> When you wish to sign the user out of the app, it is not sufficient to clear your app's cookies or otherwise end the session with the user. You must also redirect the user to the `end_session_endpoint` for sign-out. If you fail to do so, the user will be able to reauthenticate to your app without entering their credentials again, because they will have a valid single sign-on session with the Azure AD endpoint.
>
> You can simply redirect the user to the `end_session_endpoint` listed in the OpenID Connect metadata document:
>
> ```
> GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/logout?post_logout_redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
> ```
>
> **Parameter**: post_logout_redirect_uri recommended
>
> **Description**: The URL that the user should be redirected to after successful logout. If not included, the user is shown a generic message.

Also, there is an offical sample in C# [`Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out`](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-web-single-sign-out) which you can refer to.